# NodeJS, after sending the buffer through socket console says it's not a buffer

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sockets, encryption

I am trying to implement the AES encryption in ECB mode. There is the code.

```
function encrypt (key, iv, plaintext) {
    if(algorithm == 'aes-128-ecb') iv = new Buffer('');
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);    
    cipher.setAutoPadding(true);
    var ciphertext = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(plaintext), cipher.final()]);        
    return ciphertext; }

function decrypt (key, iv, ciphertext) {
    if(algorithm == 'aes-128-ecb') iv = new Buffer('');
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);    
    decipher.setAutoPadding(true); 
    var plaintext = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(ciphertext), decipher.final()]);
    return plaintext; }
```

When I encrypt the buffer I send it through a socket like this:

```
content = AES.encrypt(clients.getKeyOf(clientID), '', _msg);

            _msg = {clientID: clientID,
                    username: username,
                    timestamp: date.getHours() + ":" + ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2),
                    isEncrypted: isEncrypted,
                    content: content};

clientSocket.write( JSON.stringify(_msg));
```

And then I recieve it and try to decrypt it like this.

```
var _msg = JSON.parse(msg);
_msg.content = AES.decrypt(clients.getKeyOf(_msg.clientID), '', _msg.content);
```

The recieved data is JSON parsed to a JavaScript object, if I try to console.log it, it says it is a buffer. When I try to decrypt it the error says "Object is not a string nor a buffer."

Comment: A Buffer is not JSON serialzable, is it?

Comment: When I stringify it I get {"Type":"Buffer","Data":"xxxxxx"}. I don't get an error on parse nor any warning. What is the best way to send buffers? @Artjom B.

Answer (score 1):

It is now clear to me that buffer is not serializable, even though recieved and parsed JSON says it is a buffer it is not recognizable as one.

I got this to work by making a new buffer from received data as follows:

```
var buff = new Buffer(_msg.content);
_msg.content = AES.decrypt(clients.getKeyOf(_msg.clientID), '', buff).toString('utf8');
```